# Hotspot: how to allow only vetted devices on Android Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, wifi-hotspot

## Issue

I recently updated to a phone that could use Android Marshmallow.

I was setting up the mobile hotspot, and I could not find the option to set the hotspot so that "only allowed devices can connect".

This was an option that I used to be able to do with my old phone, which was Android version 5.0.1.  (I think that's Lollipop, right?  I cannot keep up.)

---

I also changed phones & services.  I suspect it's the OS, but here is the comparison of the two phones' details, for completeness.

Before (where I **could** set the "only allowed devices can connect" option):

- Samsung Galaxy S4 (model #SCH-I545)
- Verizon wireless service
- Android version:  5.0.1

  - Baseband version: I545VRUGOF1
  - Kernel version: 3.4.0
  - Build #: LRX22C.I545VRUGOF1
- Hardware version: I545.06
- Configuration version: J12.SAM.SCHI545.0

---

Now (where I **cannot** set the "only allowed devices can connect" option):

- Nexus 5X
- (Google) Project Fi service
- Android version: 6.0.1

  - Baseband version: M8994F-2.6.32.1.13
  - Kernel version: 3.10.73-gf215204
  - Build #: MTC19Z
- Hardware version: ?? (Cannot find it)
- Configuration version: ?? (Cannot find it)

---

## Function

Using the "only allowed devices" flag made my phone's hotspot hidden to others, so that only my validated machines can connect.  In this way, I didn't have to worry about any other machines logging on and bogging down my phone's puny hotspot (as well as any security concerns).

So, IMHO, this is a fairly powerful feature.  I use the hotspot often, and it's always within a population dense area (e.g., a train or bus).  If this is something that was stripped from the OS, what is the best way to let Google know that this is an important feature?

Comment: I believe this is a Samsung specific feature, I have not seen it in other devices, so it is probably a "Samsung Exclusive" feature, although I have seen lots of devices I cannot say for certain Samsing is the only company that has this feature. In the current pure AOSP Marshmallow code base (such as Nexus or Moto devices), there is no option to hide your SSID, limit to specific devices, or other advanced WiFi security, you are limited to only setting the SSID, the encryption off or WPA2-PSK, a password, and in multi-band devices you can set the specific band to use.

Comment: But if you have a password on the hotspot network, no one else can join, except your trusted devices? Isn't that really what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohnRamos No, it isn't exactly what I'm trying to achieve.  With the way that I had described, my phone *knew* the MAC address of my computer, and would broadcast its name only to that computer.  So, (1) I didn't have to provide a password to join the network, and (2) no one could even see it was there.  I **did** have a password most of the time, to be safe.  But it was just a much more convenient way to stay more fully hidden.  And since I was typically using it in very crowded locations, being more secure was worthwhile.

Comment: `my phone knew the MAC address of my computer` How?

Comment: Well, sounds like a TouchWiz feature.

Comment: @AADAndroidEnthusiasts Sorry, I wasn't clear.  Upon setting up the "hidden mode" of the hotspot, you first let your machine onto the hotspot network.  When it is on the network, you then say that the currently connected machine is allowed.  At that point, it's "fingerprint" is known.  Sorry, I'd give exact details, except now I cannot remember all of them any more.

Comment: @JohnRamos yeah, it seems like you're right.  I didn't realize it at the time.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this _might_ be what you're looking for: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.hotspotcontrol&hl=en

Comment: Also, what if you made your SSID something innocuous (i.e. "Linksys" or "NetGear 2.4GHz_Ext") then made your password super-long and complicated, wouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: @JohnRamos Thanks for the app link, I'll try it out!  Regarding the naming & password, you're absolutely right (although I never like overly generic names).  It's not as if I **don't have** a solution.  I simply was hoping that the "hidden hotspot" feature was something that vanilla Android Marshmallow had.